# Thenable function. Different return type on call or `await` /`then` applied

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types

in js is simple exmaple

```
function thenable() {

    return ['just function']
}
thenable.then = (resolve) => {
  resolve('like a Promise')
}
(async function main() {
  //behave like a function 
  const functionResult = thenable()
  //behave like a Promise
  const promiseLikeResult = await thenable
})()
```

Is it possible to type this behavior with typescript, when you call it's like function it returns `string[]`(['just function']) when `then` or `await` applied it returns `string` ('like a Promise')?

Comment: I wonder if this is an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want the function to do two markedly different things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. When returning its value, the function has no way of knowing whether you're going to look for `then` on it (which is what both explicitly calling `then` and `await` both do).

There are various things you could do instead, but they seem overcomplicated and like potential maintenance concerns (vs. just having two functions each with a single clearly-defined behavior) without a *really* strong use case:

- You could return a function that returns a function that also has a `then` on it, and then have the returned function do one thing while `then` on it does something else.
- You could return an object with a `then` method (e.g., a thenable) that also implements `toString` and `valueOf`, doing different things in those than it does when you call `then`. But that relies on the calling code to trigger those methods (explicitly or implicitly).
- You could return a thenable object that also has a `now` method or similar that the calling code can use to get the value you want returned when it's not a promise.

Of those three, the third seems to me like its probably the clearest and easiest to maintain, but I still lean toward two separate functions.